# Is there a way to refresh Spyder's Variable Explorer while a program is running?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

This would really help with debugging and just be a pretty useful feature. Not sure if I am just missing something or it is not an available feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) No, there isn't and it's not possible to implement such functionality at the moment, sorry.